# What is Yoda's gender? Is the character male, female, or undefined?

Tags: star-wars, yoda

Someone in my office says the character's gender was not defined; I thought Yoda was clearly male. Which one is it?

Comment: I hope nobody will goes for Rule 34 with this...

Comment: Also, this being SciFi, there are always options OTHER than M/F/NULL

Comment: @DavRob60 - Yes. Google is the first thing I bookmark on any browser.

Comment: @DVK et all - Sorry to be buzz kill, but some have objected to the Yoda link. Is it going to bother anyone if I remove it?

Comment: @MarkRogers - won't bother me. It didn't exactly add useful content :) Axe away!

Comment: @SunnyBoy : Do you need any more help with this question?

Answer (score 66):

[The Empire Strikes Back script](https://web.archive.org/web/20111223111136/http://www.blueharvest.net/scoops/esb-script.shtml) treats Yoda as male:

> LUKE: I'm not looking for a friend, I'm looking for a Jedi Master.
>
> CREATURE: Oohhh. Jedi Master. Yoda. You seek Yoda.
>
> LUKE: You know **him**?
>
> CREATURE: Mmm. Take you to **him**, I will. (laughs) Yes, yes. But now, we
>   must eat. Come. Good food. Come.
>
> With that, the creature scurries out of the clearing, laughing
>   merrily. Luke stares after **him**. All he sees is the faint light from
>   the small power lamp moving through the fog. Luke makes his decision
>   and starts after the creature.

[Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Yoda) states that Yoda is male, citing [The New Essential Guide to Characters](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_New_Essential_Guide_to_Characters). For contrast, compare Yoda to [Yaddle](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Yaddle), a female of his species.