# What species is Yoda?

Tags: star-wars

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Where is the rest of Yoda's species?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6199/where-is-the-rest-of-yodas-species)

Reading a comment on this question [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9620/what-is-yodas-gender-is-the-character-male-female-or-undefined)  about Yoda being male and another *Insert species here* Yaddle being female I started wondering what species is Yoda?

Comment: also see http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6199/where-is-the-rest-of-yodas-species

Comment: [Muppet?](http://muppet.wikia.com/wiki/Yoda)

Comment: [It is unknown what species he is. It is known simply as 'Yoda's species'.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A name, you seek? **[Yoda's species](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yoda%27s_species)**, they are. Listed as such under [Yoda's profile](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yoda), they are.

Know more, I do not.

Comment: . . .no choice you had.  Obvious the response was.

Comment: with formatting like that, how could i not accept it ;)