# What exactly is Yoda? A primate?

Tags: star-wars, yoda

I realize we cannnot necessarily apply our Terran classifications to all *Star Wars* aliens, but it is clear that many aliens are intended to be obviously primate, feline, reptilian, insectoid, etc.

In doing a cursory search, I found [this article](https://www.theguardian.com/film/2013/nov/21/star-wars-yoda-monkey-lego-characters) that explains that Yoda was originally going to be played by a monkey in a mask (!).

The green suggests a reptile, but of course, the hair and the wide variety of colours of humanoids in *Star Wars* suggest otherwise.   Do we even know if he's warm-blooded?  Is Grogu's liking of frogs (for a snack) meaningful evidence?

**Do we have any in-universe or out-of-universe evidence of what classification of animal Yoda's species is?**

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9630/58193) which is itself marked as a duplicate of [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6199/58193).

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: I do not see how these are duplicates. Those questions are asking for historical and sociological background of Yoda's species, not what the species is biologically.

Comment: "*the illegitimate child of Kermit the Frog and Miss Piggy*"

Comment: So “what species is Yoda?” Is not asking what the species of Yoda is?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot The intent of the question seems to be more like "what taxonomic class or order is Yoda", which would (presumably) be answered by knowing his species, but can also (hypothetically) be answered without it.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - I think we can ask what *class* of animal he is without knowing his species name. I've no idea what [this thing](https://static.boredpanda.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/strange-unusual-animals-38-5af5a336657d6-png__700.jpg) is, but it's clearly a mammal of some description.

Comment: And on reflection, learning the *name* of his species wouldn't necessarily tell us anything about sort of animal he is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is the rest of Yoda's species?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6199/where-is-the-rest-of-yodas-species)

Comment: @DJClayworth - I don't see that as a duplicate. I guess you could conclude from Lucas' throwaway remark that he's an amphibian, but I'm pretty sure he was joking

Comment: @Valorum “it's clearly a mammal of some description” — I’m not sure we can  confidently say that without seeing its infant suckling on its teat, and I’m not messing up my search history looking for that.

Comment: Yoda is what you get when an elf mates with a dwarf.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - It's definitely a mammal though. It couldn't be anything else.

Comment: You've heard of aliens being described as "little green men"?  That's Yoda.

Comment: Yoda definitely holds the rank of Jedi Master, not Primate: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primate_(bishop)

Comment: @Valorum: Because it's an Earth animal, and we know there are no groups of animals beside mammals that have any species looking even remotely similar to that. In an alien fauna, I'm not sure we can make any conclusions beyond characteristics such as predator/herbivore or cold-blooded/warm-blooded etc.

Answer (score 33):

### Official evidence

The only official sources I've found that explicitly describe Yoda's species don't offer any definite answer to what type of organism he is. That said, here's the relevant information that is offered:

- *The New Essential Guide to Alien Species* (2006, Legends) characterizes the species based on the examples of Yoda, Yaddle, and Vandar (from *Knights of the Old Republic*). It describes the species as "bipedal" and "humanoid" and characterizes it as having hair and "gnarled fingers". The only "new" information is a a mention of the species's "strange tastes in food, often consuming meals that others could not even bear to smell", although this could just be in- or out-of-universe extrapolation from Yoda's rootleaf stew.

  - Note that its classification as "humanoid" doesn't answer this either way, since explicitly reptilian species such as Duros are also described as humanoid within the same guide.
- *The Complete Star Wars Encyclopedia* (2008, Legends) doesn't have an entry for it.
- *Alien Archive* (2019, Canon) doesn't describe the species at all, just listing it under the name "Unknown" and describing its "ancient and secretive nature", then including a biography of Yoda.

Speculatively, it's unlikely that this will ever be answered definitively, for the same reasons that Yoda's species hasn't been explored—George Lucas felt that any definition of Yoda's background would be detrimental to the character, and Lucasfilm under Disney seems to feel the same way.

### Speculation

- Every member of Yoda's species seen so far (Yoda, Yaddle, Grogu, and Legends examples Vandar and Minch) has had hair. On Earth this would imply that they were **mammalian**.
- Yoda's species also has forward-facing eyes, which in real life ([according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binocular_vision#Field_of_view_and_eye_movements)) is typically only seen in vertebrates among primates, carnivorous mammals, and birds of prey.

  - Note, however, that this isn't necessarily the case in Star Wars—reptilian aliens such as Trandoshans also have forward-facing eyes.
- Yoda's species also has visible ear pinnae, which [in real life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auricle_(anatomy)#In_other_species) only exist in **mammals**.
- Likewise for [cheeks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheek_pouch).
- We see Grogu eat small animals and eggs in *The Mandalorian*, and Yoda eats rootleaf stew in *The Empire Strikes Back* and hunts for meat in the canon comic *The Trial of Dagobah*. This indicates that the species is **omnivorous**. This, however, doesn't shed much light on what type of animal the species is, since mammals, reptiles, and birds can all be omnivores.
- In works such as *Clone Wars* (2003, Legends) and the arc of *The Clone Wars* on Ilum, where Yoda has been seen in cold environments, he hasn't shown obvious signs of discomfort:

[image: Screenshot of Yoda on Ilum in The Clone Wars]

He also sometimes wears a hooded cloak in the cold, which would be of limited use for a cold-blooded creature:

[image: Screenshot of Yoda in a cloak on Ilum in Clone Wars (2003)]

He also uses a blanket on Dagobah, which would be actively unhelpful for a cold-blooded creature near a fire:

[image: Screenshot of Yoda under a blanket in Return of the Jedi]

From this, it seems likely that Yoda's species is **warm-blooded**.

Given the evidence that we have, Yoda's species appears to be closer to primates than to any other real-world type of animal. That said, it's unclear whether these similarities were deliberate, or if the creators of these works just gave the species human-like attributes out of familiarity (see [TVTropes: Humanoid Aliens](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HumanoidAliens)).